# WSL > Ruby (Rails) Server

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ruby, rubymine

I am starting the ruby (rails) server on WSL (using Ruby Mine on Windows) and open the browser but I get the message in windows browsers (used chrome):

Thanks for your help!
Julian

PS: it worked before

---

PG::ConnectionBad
could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Extracted source (around line #56):

```
### Convenience alias for PG::Connection.new.
def self::connect( *args )
    return PG::Connection.new( *args )
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "worked before"? How does one can start ruby server (WSL) from Ruby mine (Windows)?

Comment: Could you please also check how it goes in case you start a rails server manually (not via RubyMine)?

Comment: how to start a rails server in windows?